# Unable to select table inside a table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently having problem selecting table inside table using **jquery** what i want is to select the second table inside the table as given in **HTML** code below. I have tried the following **jquery** code but when i use it adds the first `tr` with `style="display:none;"` as i wrote it down below to show the `tr` it selects but rather i want to select the third `table tr`. can anyone please help  me select the right `table`.

Here is what i tried:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").hide();
});
    </script>

         <table width="79%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="350">
              <tr style="display:none;">
                    <td valign="top" width="1%" bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="78%" bgcolor=#FFFFFF>



                    <center>
                    <br><b><u>COURSE PAGE - Winter Semester 2015~16</u></b><br /><br />



                    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' align='center' border='1' width='95%' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='black'>

                        <tr align=center bgcolor=#5A768D>
                            <td width=80><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Owner</font></td>
                            <td width=70><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Code</font></td>
                            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Title</font></td>
                            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Type</font></td>
                            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Faculty</font></td>
                            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Class Nbr(s)</font></td>
                            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Slot(s)</font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor='#E1ECF2'>
                            <td width=80 align=center>SITE</td>
                            <td width=70 align=center>ITE302</td>
                            <td>Database Systems</td>
                            <td>Embedded Lab</td>
                            <td>11543 - SARAVANAKUMAR K - SITE</td>
                            <td>2039</td>
                            <td>L29+L30</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table><br>

                    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' width="95%" align='center' border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='black' height="61">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30"><font color=#FFFFFF>Syllabus</font></td>
                        <form action='syllabus_file.asp' method='post'><td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width='75%' height='30'><input type='hidden' name='crscd' value='ITE302'><input type='hidden' name='crstp' value='ELA'><input type='hidden' name='version' value='1'><input type='submit' name='sybcmd' class='submit' value='Download'></td></form>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=5 valign=top>
                            <font color=#FFFFFF>Text/Reference Material</font>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
                            <a href='https://academics.vit.ac.in/faculty/Syllabus_Textbook/WINSEM2015-16_CP1673_TB01_DBMS_Lab_Manual.pdf' target='_blank'><font color=blue>DBMS_Lab_Manual.pdf</font></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
                            <a href='https://academics.vit.ac.in/faculty/Syllabus_Textbook/WINSEM2015-16_CP1673_TB02_Structured-Query-Language.pdf' target='_blank'><font color=blue>Structured-Query-Language.pdf</font></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
                            <a href='https://academics.vit.ac.in/faculty/Syllabus_Textbook/WINSEM2015-16_CP1673_TB03_students_manual.pdf' target='_blank'><font color=blue>students_manual.pdf</font></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </table><br>



                    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' width="95%" align='center' border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='black' height="61">

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=5 valign=top>
                            <font color=#FFFFFF>Assignments</font>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                            NIL
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </table><br>
```

Comment: Where is your `<script>` tag?

Comment: come on, i know i already added that.

Comment: It wasn't added in your code!!! Be specific.

Comment: Now it seems there is no `$(document).ready()` ...

Comment: sorry about that added.

Comment: *what i want is to select the second table inside the table* ...So you want the 2nd nested table... *rather i want to select the third table tr* ...So you want the 3rd row of the 2nd nested table, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are targetting `td` of a `table` inside `td`, you need to specify `table` inside `table` as below:

```
$("table table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").hide();
```

or to be precise `table` inside `td` as:

```
$("table td table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").hide();
```

Otherwise your condition will satisfy always at very first instance and it will hide the root `tr` since there is `NIL` in `table` which is inside `td`

> **Make a note -**  I don't understand why you have added `display:none;` on the very first `tr` and I've removed that.

---

**Sinppet**

```js
 $("table table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="79%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="350">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="1%" bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="78%" bgcolor=#FFFFFF>



      <center>
        <br><b><u>COURSE PAGE - Winter Semester 2015~16</u></b>
        <br />
        <br />



        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' align='center' border='1' width='95%' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='black'>

          <tr align=center bgcolor=#5A768D>
            <td width=80><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Owner</font>
            </td>
            <td width=70><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Code</font>
            </td>
            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Title</font>
            </td>
            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Course Type</font>
            </td>
            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Faculty</font>
            </td>
            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Class Nbr(s)</font>
            </td>
            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Slot(s)</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor='#E1ECF2'>
            <td width=80 align=center>SITE</td>
            <td width=70 align=center>ITE302</td>
            <td>Database Systems</td>
            <td>Embedded Lab</td>
            <td>11543 - SARAVANAKUMAR K - SITE</td>
            <td>2039</td>
            <td>L29+L30</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <br>

        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' width="95%" align='center' border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='black' height="61">
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30"><font color=#FFFFFF>Syllabus</font>
            </td>
            <form action='syllabus_file.asp' method='post'>
              <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width='75%' height='30'>
                <input type='hidden' name='crscd' value='ITE302'>
                <input type='hidden' name='crstp' value='ELA'>
                <input type='hidden' name='version' value='1'>
                <input type='submit' name='sybcmd' class='submit' value='Download'>
              </td>
            </form>
          </tr>



          <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=5 valign=top>
              <font color=#FFFFFF>Text/Reference Material</font>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
              <a href='https://academics.vit.ac.in/faculty/Syllabus_Textbook/WINSEM2015-16_CP1673_TB01_DBMS_Lab_Manual.pdf' target='_blank'><font color=blue>DBMS_Lab_Manual.pdf</font></a>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
              <a href='https://academics.vit.ac.in/faculty/Syllabus_Textbook/WINSEM2015-16_CP1673_TB02_Structured-Query-Language.pdf' target='_blank'><font color=blue>Structured-Query-Language.pdf</font></a>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
              <a href='https://academics.vit.ac.in/faculty/Syllabus_Textbook/WINSEM2015-16_CP1673_TB03_students_manual.pdf' target='_blank'><font color=blue>students_manual.pdf</font></a>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="75%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <br>



        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' width="95%" align='center' border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;' bordercolor='black' height="61">

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=5 valign=top>
              <font color=#FFFFFF>Assignments</font>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
              NIL
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <br>
```

Comment: Since `thrid table`'s all the `td` have `NIL` in them none of the `tr` will show up which basically means whole `table` will hide with no rows to be shown.. Add a value to any `td` and it will come up..